# Trying To Work Out What This 3rd Party Script Is Sending From My Settings

Tags: security, encryption

I've just visited a website that I believe is sending my personal data to a 3rd party. In chrome developer tools (Network Tab) I can see that a payload is being sent to a 3rd party location with "beginpersonalisation" in the URL. The payload looks to be encrypted, or is it obfuscated? Sorry I don't know much about encryption. My question is does anybody recognize this type of string? And is there any way I can reverse-engineer it so I can see what is going on?

&analytics=eQ%2241%3B%C2%BFQ%16%C2%98%C2%88%C2%83U%19L%C2%83%C2%83%C2%ADc'%C2%A4r4%C2%85U%C2%8FYY%03%1D%C3%94%C2%A2%5E1%C3%9D%C2%88%C2%9C_%5DG%C2%84%C3%87%C2%B9%C2%A9J%C2%AC%C2%97%C3%A9%16%C2%BF%11%C2%BA%C2%97%C3%81%C2%88%C3%AB%C3%98%C2%B5i%C3%8D%C2%92%C2%B1%0BI%C3%96%C3%B0%C3%AD%C3%8A%C3%BB%C2%9A%C3%B5%C2%AC%C3%AF%C2%A4%3DD%13%C3%8B%C3%8AH%1A%C3%8C%C3%A7%0F%00%C3%9DE%168%C3%BDk%C2%91%3A1%C2%A2%7D%5E8G%C2%85Mm%0E3%C2%8EN%C2%85s%03%06%C2%B4%3C%1Dz_9%C2%8D%C3%86%23%5Cl%C3%A6%C3%A8*%16%C2%96)V%C2%81%C3%B7L%7DU%3D%1A%C3%9C%C3%8A%C2%82.%C3%80%C3%BE%0BP%0EH%C2%80%C2%B5%C3%AERt%C3%A7T%C3%A0%04%C2%AD.%19%C3%8B%13%C3%83%C3%99%C2%8Bzf%C3%91%C3%A3I%C3%80%26%10o%17%C2%8C%C3%8F%C3%89%02%11-%0E%C3%AFE%C3%A4e6%5Dk%C2%AE%C3%B3%C2%B3c%5C%23ns%C2%B0Mv%15I%C3%8D%22r%C3%883%C2%97%C2%B8%C2%93%19%C3%96%C3%BE%3E%C3%82%C3%99O%178%C3%9Ab%5EA%C2%BE%C3%BE%7DF(%C2%AA%C2%B1S%3El.%C2%B45%C3%BC%C3%9C0%C3%8C0%C3%89!%C2%BC%C2%8E0%C3%B5%1E6%C2%8B%C3%83%C2%95%C3%82P%C2%9A%C3%94%C2%80%C2%BE%C3%87%C3%90k%C2%97*%C2%9Em%20%1Bv%C3%86%0DF%C3%A5d%C2%91%C2%9AD%2F%2CB%20%26%C2%8B%C3%B7%17C%C3%80%20V-%C2%A4%C3%8E%C2%A9%C2%99R%C2%BAg%C2%97%C3%862bW53%C3%9E%C3%A8E%C3%91%C3%B9r4%02%C2%BA%C3%8F%7F%C3%86d%C2%B2%C3%AAkB%C3%9F%C3%B1%C2%81%C3%92%C2%88%C2%81%3DR%0C%C2%83%C3%84b%C2%A9%C2%BE%C3%8A'%C3%8F%24%12R%C3%B6w%C2%A3%C3%94P%C3%A2%260%C2%8B%C3%86%7F%C3%B4A%C3%8A%04%C2%98%C2%8E%3D%C2%89%C2%B0G%C2%AD%C2%AE%12(%C3%80u%C2%94n%23%C2%A5%1Dn%C3%8F%C2%A3vG%C3%BBEf%C3%9E%1E%3A%00%0E%C3%9B%C2%B95%C3%86%C2%A2%C3%8C%C2%B6%C2%95Cpr%26%03%C3%9E%0B%C3%AFzH%5C%C2%86r8%5E%1F%16%1E%02s(%C2%BF%C2%8C%C3%9A%C3%BE%3C%C2%AAb%C2%9C%16J%C2%BFh%C3%B0%00%C3%96vGc%14%C2%87%C3%B4s%C2%82%C3%B6C%5B%C3%86%044t%C3%AB%08%0B%C2%A2%C3%93%C2%A1%C2%B5%C2%83%C2%9BQu%C3%A2%C2%81%C2%B5%C2%93%C2%9D%C2%8B%C3%BD%16%0B%C3%A0qt%C2%99c.%C2%A2u%C3%B0%031%C2%B1%3A%C3%B8%0D%C2%B21%10%C3%95%C3%BC%C3%8Awv%2CM7vEh%C2%BF%C3%BE%19%C3%AE%C2%9Bk%3B%C3%ABO%13*OO%C3%86%C2%98v%C3%83~FO%C2%B9%C2%9D%C2%A3%C2%86%C2%84%0A%C3%BC%1E%04%60%C2%A3%C3%90%05%C2%82%C2%9D~%2B%C2%ABM%C2%9E%C2%9Dl%C2%92.%05%C3%81%7F%C2%92%C2%BC5-Y-F%C2%81%C2%9C%C3%B9%C3%8C%C3%AC%C2%9D%C2%BB%C2%9A%C2%96%C2%B2%05'%C2%A2%C3%8B%C2%8E%C3%84%C2%A7Z%C2%9E%3B%40j%1B%C3%98%7C%C3%80%C3%A9%5C%20%C2%ADFB%19P%10%C2%8C%3Bc-%C3%85%03BL%C3%9D%3A%C2%9AZ%C2%93%C3%B2%C3%AF%C3%98%C3%862%C2%B1K%C3%91u%C3%A3Gv0%C2%B1D%C2%BFL%C3%AD%1B%C3%A6%04%C3%B9%C2%87%C3%8Cy%C2%B6%C3%AB%C3%91%C2%A1%C3%9B%C2%81%2F%C2%AEs%25T%C3%9D%C2%80%C3%96%C2%86r%C2%986%C2%9FQ%C3%86%0B%C3%91%13%C2%B2%1C5%C2%9D%26%3F%C3%89%1E%C3%A19%12%5En%C2%9F%C2%95%14%7B%C3%8B%2BV%3F%C3%86%C2%95%C3%B2Fb7%C3%BE%C2%BF!%C2%A3%1F%C2%8F%06%C3%BE%C2%82%7D%C3%B87GE%C3%80%0AS%02%C2%9B%C2%9A%2FvJP%C3%B7%C2%AB%2C%C3%90%C3%84%40%5C%0A%C2%A0%C3%BD%02%C3%94%C3%91SL%C3%BD%C2%8C%C3%A2%C3%86%C2%B2%5E%C3%B9V%C3%B3%2F%3D%C2%B7%0AZ%C3%86%10%0E%C2%BC%2C%08%C3%B50%09%3Aqc%C2%83%C2%98%C2%A1r%C2%BFj%C3%99%C2%87%C2%98O%C3%A6*5%C3%A6J%C2%A2H%C3%A3%06qBb%C2%B2%C3%BE%0E!w%C3%82%C2%90%07rR%C2%A8%C3%90%12%C3%AD%60%C3%A2%09%C3%92%C3%8Aa%C3%95%C2%BAu%7F%C2%8E%C2%BD%0EH%C3%B1%C2%9DF%C3%A7%C3%AD%C2%A2%C2%A6~%C2%AD%C2%B8%C2%A3sd%7B%C2%B6%C2%96%C3%8F%C3%A4%C2%9D%1C(qH%C2%BB%C2%B3%C3%AAQ'%24%C3%BAj%08%5C%C3%AF(%C3%8DY5E%C2%B0%1B%C2%8E%13%60%C2%AC%C2%94m%19%C3%90%C2%AD%C3%8DQ%C2%AE%C3%9BQA%C3%AD%7F-%C3%AB%C2%A5%C3%83%01%C3%96%1F%C3%BC%3DB%C2%A1%22f%C3%B5%C3%A1%C2%9FR%14%16!%C2%A2%C2%A0%C3%9BoS%C2%BD%C3%B1%C3%AE%C2%8Ej%2B%26KRAA%C2%8Dm%C3%ABb2%C2%80%12~%C2%88%5B%24%04%15%C3%A7%C3%B5%5B%13d%16Li%7Dqq%C2%BB%24%C3%A8N%C3%9F%5C%23%C3%B0%C2%B5%C3%93%24%C3%95%C2%80%1D%C3%BF%C3%AF%C2%BF-%12%07V%C2%96%7D!%C3%89%C3%94%C2%82%3A%C3%91%C3%B5%C3%94%C3%8B%C2%B5X*%1C%5B%1A%7D%C2%91%C2%94b%C3%B6%C2%AF%C2%8B%C2%B5c%C3%99%C3%93%C2%9C%C3%93%07%C3%9F%C2%96%C2%9Ey%25%C2%A7%1E%226C%2F%22%40%C2%90%C2%8C%05%C3%82%C3%99%40O%C2%999%C2%BC%C2%87%C3%AB.%C2%A2%C3%A15%C2%B6%C2%A5%153%C3%9F3%C3%98%C3%95R%C2%86*%C3%BD%C2%BD%7DE%C2%AA%1D%40%C3%A2%C2%B5%C3%A2%5C%C3%BA%0D%C3%BB%C2%BD%C3%A2%2Fecf%C2%90%C2%AF%C3%96%C3%AD%C3%82k%16%3B%C3%BF3'%C2%97%C3%A5c%5BMUb*8%7C%C2%98%C3%B6W%0B%C3%8F%C3%BD%26%20%C2%BD%24%C3%A2%C2%BCm%C2%95B1%C3%86%C3%B1%C2%96%C2%9B%C2%A5%12%C3%956%045%C3%81%C2%81%3E5b%12%C2%BA%C2%8E%24h%10xq%0C%C2%83%C3%87y%22*w%C2%8Dcu%5B%C2%88%C2%B6%C2%A1%C2%AF4%C3%99%C2%B8AI%25%08%C2%89%3C%C2%AE%1C%C2%B7%3E%C3%BFO%C3%A8%C2%8B%C3%85%C2%99tA%C2%A2f%C2%99%C2%8FVCQ%C2%9D%13%C3%91J%06_%C2%B7%C2%8C*%0F%C3%91)%05%C3%A1%C2%81k%1E%C2%9E%C2%81v%3BB%C2%87%15%C2%85%C2%AC5FW%C3%88X%C3%AB%C3%93%C2%9A%C3%BA%C3%BBq~%C2%8B%C2%90%C2%89%C3%8B%C2%96%20%03%C3%A6%C3%BA%C3%BBm%26%C2%A7%046%C2%A8%0Er%C2%B8%C2%95%C3%BC8%0C%0F%16%C3%BD%C2%80%C3%9F%40-%3F%C3%B8%C2%A9%C3%B0%C3%AA%C3%823N%C3%B5%C3%84%C2%80%1C%1A%C2%9DfQ%C3%AEW9%1Ei%C3%B2%C2%A4%C3%86%C2%80~%C2%9E%C2%92%C3%B2%0E%C3%AB%C2%9E%C3%A7k%C2%A8%C2%9D%C3%82%C2%B2LnI%175%C2%80iI%C3%AB%C2%BA%C2%8F%C3%AA%16E%C2%9Bo%C3%9F%C3%A8S%C3%BB%C3%AA%C3%9F%09%24U%25%C2%9D%2F%C3%9D%06%C3%B4%C2%A6%00I%C2%91%03%C2%9F%C2%AF%C3%B3%17%C3%80%C3%8B%24%1DXe%C3%96c%C2%979%16%04b%C3%95%C3%A1go%03L%C2%B8%C3%86J%C3%B7%C2%8EB%194%5E%03%0D%C3%94%C2%B4%C2%B0%5B%C2%A6Ki%C3%89%14%C3%87%C3%B9%14%C2%A1%C2%85%C2%AA%60%C3%AC%C2%9E%7C%2CW.%08%C2%B930%07%C2%AD%C3%B8%7F_%C3%94%1C%07f%C2%BA%14%2C%1A%3A%C2%88%09%2C%C3%A0%06B%C3%B00%C3%92%01%C3%AF%C3%83%C2%A9%C2%80%C2%998%0D%C3%8AvK%C2%8A%7C%C2%82%C2%B3%C2%AC%C2%A7%C3%81%20%C2%BF%C3%9E%3C%0F%0C%C3%8Bp%5D%C2%B2N%C2%82%1E%C2%BC%C3%BCEg%C3%8EKIQ%C2%BDBC%7D%C2%903%7C%05l%C3%83o%3D%C2%A1%17%23%19L%08%C3%A8%C2%98%C2%A2w%7BpSu%C3%9A%C2%90%C2%A1)c%C2%ACz%C2%A8%C3%82p%C2%B0%7B%C3%AA9%C3%B5Z%C3%A6%1D%C3%A6o%C2%BF%C2%BB%C3%93%C2%A4%C2%82%19%C3%97b%C2%94%C2%9C%C2%B1%C3%9BF%C3%84*)U%40%0AS%C3%B6%C3%AA%C3%AA%C3%88%C3%AA%C3%9Ax%C2%9B%C2%80-%C3%86%C2%BD%C2%BA%C3%99%1B%C2%81%C2%A9%C2%9B%C3%B7%C3%A2%C2%A9%C3%85%C3%86Q%C3%A3O%C3%A8%5E%1E%01f%3C%C3%B7%C3%A0%C2%B8%25%C3%84%C3%91O%C2%9F%C2%B0*%C2%99m%03%0F%C2%9B%C3%B8%C2%978%C2%B7%40y%1DS%C3%BBHR9%C3%8C%C3%A5%C3%AE%C3%9DV%C2%BCl%C3%AB%C3%8D%19*%C2%86%15em%2C6%0F%C2%B7%2F04p7%C3%AE%C2%BD%C3%B7%C2%8E%C2%8C.%7C%C3%98.%C3%BF3SQ%5E'%C3%9AX%25%C2%80%C3%A5%1C%C3%B1xuei%2C%C3%87%C2%A8%C2%8F%26S%C2%9C%C2%BC%C3%BC%00!%C3%B3%7D%C2%A5(%02%C3%A0%C2%81%24hl%C3%8A%C2%A0v%5D%C2%BF%1Eoi%C2%83%0F%C2%B2%C2%86%C3%84%12%C2%98%C3%82%5E%C2%88%2Fq%C2%AC%C3%96%C3%88%C2%B5%14)%C3%99%C3%A9%C3%97%C2%BB%C3%90%C3%93V%C2%99%C2%B1%C2%BD%C3%B0%C2%B7C%25F7%2B%10(%04%C2%B0%C2%91%C3%B2%0D4%C2%9D5OT%C2%AA%C3%AE%C2%BE%C2%AD_U%03%C3%B1%13%22%C3%B7c%0C%18%C3%AD%C3%BB%C2%83E%23%C3%8A%C3%850%3D%C2%A5%C3%A22%C2%A8~%2C%C3%9D%40%03%C3%8CwrL%197%12E%23%2F8%01%0C%C3%9C%5B%C3%A4%C2%97%15%C2%94%00d%C3%A1%C3%A9%0C%C2%81%5C%C2%8BR%C2%86H%C2%ADO%C3%96%C2%AB_%C2%9D.%C3%8E(%C2%A6k%C2%BCuN%02%C2%98%C3%AA%1C%C3%BB%C2%A8%C3%AB%C2%B1_%C2%83%C3%95%5C'%10%C2%B0U%C3%82vS%C3%A8%17%3F4%03c%C2%A4%C2%9D%C3%9En%C3%9AN%3C%C2%8D%C3%8B%C3%BF%06%C2%92D%13%C3%92to%15%047%5E%C3%9B%C2%8C%00%C3%AAw%2B%C3%B8%23%C2%8A%06%C2%9D%C2%AB%25p%C3%8C%08US8%C2%B2%C3%B6%C2%A1%C2%97%C2%B4%C3%92%C2%9D'%C2%9AZo%C3%A1%C2%B5%C3%88)i%5C%7D%23I%C2%BF%C2%89rhQO%09%C3%91%C3%ADr2%C3%AE%C2%B6j%11%C2%95%C2%A0%C2%AF%C3%B6%C3%AEHi%C2%B2%C3%83%04%23N%C3%ACSuo%C3%B8%10I%C2%83%C2%A4%3F%C3%95%C3%96%C3%A1%C3%88t%C3%B9%C3%B3%06I%C3%B9JMc%0B%C2%BFB%C3%81%0A%C3%ACa%C3%BC%C2%AC%C3%A2%C3%81%5Ez%C2%89%C3%90(%C3%BA%06%C2%AC%C2%BA%C3%91L%C2%BF%0F%C3%82%C2%9D%3E%C3%BE%0B%C3%BD%C2%B5%C2%9A%C2%9CDYw%C2%A78G%C3%91%C3%929%C3%8C%C2%BD%C3%B6%C3%AC%C2%AEhM%C3%90%5C%C3%A8%C2%82Sh%C3%B1K%C3%A0%C2%BEV%C3%AEwz7%C3%AFsus%C2%B8x%C2%9B%01%C2%B6!%C2%B4%C2%BB%C3%92%C3%AB%C2%AE%C3%84%40%2FX%3A%C3%A6%C3%BF%C3%8Cl%C2%94%C2%92%14%C2%99%C3%94%C2%BAH%C3%8C%C3%84%C3%95%7B%C2%8E%C3%AAX%3D%C3%BD%C2%B7k

Comment: There is nothing encrypted in the string. It using standard rules to submit a GET request to a web site. I have no idea why your query string is that size though. Thanks.

Comment: It does look encrypted (and of course URL encoded). To know what it contains you'd have to reverse-engineer the script that send it. The script only has access to what you granted to the site, it could be just some innocent settings.